# How would dependency injection apply to this scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm using Ninject for constructor injection to create my concrete objects on the fly.  However, I have a scenario where the class contains a method that accepts a string.  Based on the value of the string, I would like to obtain a specific class.  I accomplished this by creating a factory class to return the concrete class but wasn't sure if this was the best way.  Any suggestions?

```
//Service class
public int GetEmployeeVacationDays(string employeeType)
{
  IEmployee employee = EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee(employeeType);
  return employee.VacationDays();
}

//Factory class
public static IEmployee CreateEmployee(string employeeType)
{
   if(employeeType == "Salary")
   {
      return new SalariedEmployee();
   }
   else
   {
      return new HourlyEmployee();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency injection doesn't apply to your scenario. That's the factory pattern. You could configure Ninject to use the factory pattern to provide dependencies if you will for certain objects.

In fact you could entire replace the factory pattern with named bindings:

```
Bind<IEmployee>().To<FooEmployee>().Named("foo");
Bind<IEmployee>().To<BarEmployee>().Named("bar");
Bind<IEmployee>().To<BazEmployee>().Named("baz");
```

Comment: Okay, so the factory pattern I'm implementing is fine then.  I'm not totally clear on your bindings example as I've only used that for constructor injection.  My code is a specific method within the class.

Comment: @Beavis, yes the factory pattern is fine.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that employeeType is a valid class name:

```
return System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className))
```

Comment: Right, [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) takes a string. So like `Class Test {...}` employeeType would have to be `"Test"`. That is what I'm saying.